# Not getting proper headers from websocket connection

Tags: javascript, java, spring-boot, spring-websocket

I have simple spring-websocket spring-bbot based application.
I have controller which detects websocket connection from client:

```
@Controller
public class WebSocketMessageHandler {
    private final RequestService requestService;
    private final Map<String, ChatSession> chatSessions;

    private static final String CLIENT_HEADER = "clientId";
    private static final String OPERATOR_HEADER = "operatorId";


    public WebSocketMessageHandler(RequestService requestService, Map<String, ChatSession> chatSessions) {
        this.requestService = requestService;
        this.chatSessions = chatSessions;
    }


    @EventListener
    public void handleWebSocketConnectListener(SessionConnectedEvent event) {
        StompHeaderAccessor accessor = StompHeaderAccessor.wrap(event.getMessage());
        String sessionId = accessor.getSessionId();
        String clientId = getHeaderValue(accessor, CLIENT_HEADER);
        String operatorId = getHeaderValue(accessor, OPERATOR_HEADER);

        ChatSession session = ChatSession.builder()
                .sessionId(sessionId)
                .operatorId(operatorId)
                .clientId(clientId)
                .connectedClients(new HashSet<>() {{
                    add(clientId);
                    add(operatorId);
                }})
                .build();

        ChatSession chatSession = chatSessions.computeIfAbsent(sessionId, s -> session);
        chatSession.addClient(clientId);
    }

    
    private String getHeaderValue(StompHeaderAccessor accessor, String headerName) {
        GenericMessage<?> generic = (GenericMessage<?>) accessor.getHeader(SimpMessageHeaderAccessor.CONNECT_MESSAGE_HEADER);

        if (nonNull(generic)) {
            SimpMessageHeaderAccessor nativeAccessor = SimpMessageHeaderAccessor.wrap(generic);
            List<String> userIdValue = nativeAccessor.getNativeHeader(headerName);

            return isNull(userIdValue) ? null : userIdValue.stream().findFirst().orElse(null);
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

I connect to application using sockJS :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        let stompClient = null;
        const socket = new SockJS('http://localhost:8082/ws');
        const headers = {
            clientId: '1',
            operatorId: '2'
        }
        let sessionId;

        stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
        stompClient.connect(headers, (frame) => {
            stompClient.subscribe('/all/messages/${sessionId}', (result) => {
                show(JSON.parse(result.body));
            });

            sessionId = frame.headers['session-id'];
        });

       
    </script>
```

I have 2 problems. first one - when I try to call `accessor.getFirstNativeHeader()` I get null(though such native headers presents). Because of that, I had to create method getHeaderValue to extract it manually, but I dont understand why getFirstNativeHeader provides null on every header.

Second problem that `frame.headers` which I get on connection estabilishment, does not contain anything except `hear-beat` and `version` headers, though I need my headers in it(like sessionId).

How can I solve these problems?